# Android Viewpager2 and RecyclerView Item onClick listener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager2

I have implemented Viewpager2 Image slider using the code idea mentioned in the following link.

I want handle clicks on the slider images. How to Open another activity if the specific slider item clicked.

Here is the link of code

https://androidapps-development-blogs.medium.com/android-modern-image-slider-using-viewpager-2-and-kenburnsview-android-studio-23a7b74317e8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your adapter go to TravelLocationViewHolder.
After this line

`textLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLocation);`

try to set a click listener on itemview

`itemView.setOnClickListener( v-> { System.out.println("THIS IS IT"); } );`

Comment: Thanks Aleti! It really gave me tough time, but your just a single line worked all I wanted.

Comment: Hy, glad it helped you. can u mark it as correct answer? Thank you and enjoy coding